# How can I connect to endpoint when attempting to export data from RDS to S3?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

### Objective

My objective is to export data from a Postgres RDS Instance to an s3 Bucket. I just want to prove that the concept works on my VPC, so I am using dummy data.

### What I have tried so far

I followed the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples-prerequisites) using the console and cli.

1. Created an s3 bucket (I chose to block all public access)
2. Created an RDS Instance with the following settings:

   - Created on 2 public subnets
   - Public accessibility: No
   - Security group rules for outbound: CIDR/IP - Inbound   0.0.0.0/0
   - Security group rules for inbound: CIDR/IP - Inbound    0.0.0.0/0
3. Created a policy as shown in the example:

```
    aws iam create-policy  --policy-name rds-s3-export-policy  --policy-document '{
         "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [
           {
             "Sid": "s3export",
             "Action": [
               "S3:PutObject"
             ],
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-bucket/*"
             ] 
           }
         ] 
       }'
```

4. Created an IAM Role like:

```
aws iam create-role  --role-name rds-s3-export-role  --assume-role-policy-document '{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
          },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ] 
   }'
```

5. Attached the policy to the role like:

```
aws iam attach-role-policy  --policy-arn your-policy-arn  --role-name rds-s3-export-role
```

6. Added the IAM Role to the DB like:

```
aws rds add-role-to-db-instance \
   --db-instance-identifier my-db-instance \
   --feature-name s3Export \
   --role-arn your-role-arn   \
   --region your-region
```

7. Did all the requirements within PSQL like:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS aws_s3 CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE sample_table (bid bigint PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(80));

INSERT INTO sample_table (bid,name) VALUES (1, 'Monday'), (2,'Tuesday'), (3, 'Wednesday');

SELECT aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
   'dummy-data-bucket-path',
   '',
   'us-west-2'
) AS s3_uri_1 \gset
```

#### What does not work

When I try to make the actual export by:

```
SELECT * FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('SELECT * FROM sample_table', :'s3_uri_1');
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  could not upload to Amazon S3
DETAIL:  Amazon S3 client returned 'Unable to connect to endpoint'.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "query_export_to_s3" statement 1
```

#### Other things I have tried:

I have tried using `Access analyzer for S3` but my bucket does not seem to appear in the list. I believe as the bucket itself does not have a policy attached to it.

How can I debug this issue? What am I doing wrong? I am happy to share further details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I see from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples-prerequisites) you are following does not assume that you are running this whole setup inside a VPC.

So for connecting from within the VPC(as you have blocked all the public access) , you need to have an [endpoint policies for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#vpc-endpoints-policies-s3) attached.

for example from [documentation sample policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#vpc-endpoints-s3-bucket-policies) :

> The following is an example of an S3 bucket policy that allows access to a specific bucket, my_secure_bucket, from endpoint vpce-1a2b3c4d only.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket/*"],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Hi @samtoddler = ) My VPC currently does not have an endpoint identified. In that do I need to define an Endpoint for my VPC? or create an [S3 Access Point](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/access-points/) on the bucket? Or something else?

Comment: as per the documentation inside the vpc it is needed <We recommend that you set up your database within a private VPC that has endpoint policies configured for accessing specific buckets. For more information, see Using endpoint policies for Amazon S3 in the Amazon VPC User Guide.>