# Unable to connect to endpoint when exporting data from RDS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, export, amazon-rds, endpoint

*Objective*: my goal is to export data from RDS to S3
*What I have done so far*: I have done everything as described by another user in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617259/how-can-i-connect-to-endpoint-when-attempting-to-export-data-from-rds-to-s3)
*What does not work*: I get the same error as the user in the linked question

I understand from the answer to the linked question that the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) does not assume that you are running this whole setup inside a VPC, but I still do not understand how using an AWS S3 VPC endpoint would solve this error.

In my case, the RDS is set up inside a VPC. The VPC has 3 public subnets (i.e. all 3 subnets have access to the internet via an Internet Gateway. I checked this by looking at their route tables as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/556363/what-is-the-difference-between-a-public-and-private-subnet-in-a-amazon-vpc)). ***So why would I need an AWS S3 VPC endpoint to reach my S3 bucket and export the result of my PostgreSQL query to it?***

This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvKWJ4c1EYc) also seems to prove that adding an AWS S3 VPC endpoint would not solve the error I am getting, as he can access the s3 bucket just fine from his EC2 instance which is set up within a VPC in a public subnet.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: To solve this, write a Lambda function that uses code to retrieve the data from an RDS instance. Then within the Lambda function, use the Amazon S3 SDK to put the data into an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but wouldn't the lambda function need to store the retrieved data within its memory which has a memory limitation of 10GB? I need to query large amounts of data.